# Использование библиотеки Picasso в AIDE

Tags: java, android, jar, picasso

Здравствуйте, в связи с отсутствием компьютера и желанием идти в ногу со временем, я решил найти способ использовать сторонние библиотеки в Android IDE (AIDE). Это приложение для разработки приложений прямо на телефоне. Захотел поюзать `Picasso` и зашёл вот [сюда](http://square.github.io/picasso/) и скачал JAR архив с библиотекой. Далее я не нашёл возможности сунуть этот JAR в AIDE, поэтому придумал лайфхак.

**Что я сделал**

Я обнаружил, что AIDE использует собственный android.jar, в котором находятся .class файлы. В этом архиве есть все классы Java и Android, а также присутствует иерархия по папкам. Ясное дело, что AIDE использует этот архив для загрузки импортов.

Также я обнаружил, что JAR архив библиотеки Picasso также представляет собой иерархию файлов .class. У меня появилась идея.

**Какая?**

Я просто взял и извлек из архива папку com. Тем самым всю библиотеку  (com.squareup.picasso.*) и аккуратно положил в корень архива android.jar. Новый архив с добавленной библиотекой я положил на место и запустил AIDE. Захожу в java файл и пишу в секцию импортов

```
import com.squareup.picasso.*;
```

Работает! Далее пишу (ну так, чтобы окончательно удостовериться)

```
Picasso.with(this)
```

Дописывать и проверять не стал, ибо синтаксис подсвечен, ошибок нет. Я было хотел поделиться идеей в блоге на G+, но отложил. Сейчас пришло время поюзать библиотеку. Я решил начать с простого - отобразить в `ImageView` картинку из файла на устройстве. Эта строка кода из адаптера, к тому же я получаю из БД путь к картинке, поэтому используется курсор

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(new File(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Helper.PATH))))
.into(holder.item_photo);
```

Запускаю. И тут бац!

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;
ru.turbomedia.picassotest.MainActivity$ExpAdapter.getGroupView(MainActivity.java:376)
```

Жалуется именно на эту строчку

**Мои догадки**

Наверное, дело в том, что я совершил глупую ошибку и зря манипулировал JAR исходниками. Мне кажется, что в android.jar нельзя было добавлять библиотеку. Ведь, библиотека это набор классов и методов, которые работают внутри себя и ни от чего не зависят. А в android.jar лежат что-то типа .aidl файлов, которые нужны лишь для того, чтобы в среде разработки отображались методы, константы, классы, интерфейсы, и т.д и т.п. Среда компилирует код а он уже выполняется на устройстве, так как существует API фреймворк.

Этот вывод я сделал благодаря знаниям по созданию прошивок, но может быть некорректным.

**Что делать?**

Я таким образом добавил не только `Picasso`, но и другие популярные библитеотеки, такие как `Retrofit`, `OkHttp`, `Gson` и даже нашёл сайт с maven-repositories и забил хром закладками на понравившиеся библиотеки. Там были как JAR так и AAR архивы, которые я запланировал таким же образом добавлять и использовать. Но все-таки вовремя проверил. Есть ли какой-нибудь альтернативный рабочий способ добавить библиотеки в AIDE?

P.S  -  Не предлагайте использовать `Clone GIT Repository`, это сплошные грабли, т.к качается целая куча мусора для студии и я здорово путаюсь.

Есть вариант с ручным копированием исходников библиотек в проект, но это сплошные нервы, так как буфера обмена не хватает скопировать весь код (если брать на гитхабе) и приходится начинать все сначала из-за этого. Если качать JAR-ы, то там будут скомпилированные классы.

Comment: Постарайтесь пожалуйста сформулировать выжимку и конкретный вопрос в 1 параграфе.

Comment: Такие вопросы не привлекают особого внимания и тем более объяснить хочется внятно, чтобы было понятно что я именно сделал

Comment: Отчасти поэтому и не привлекают внимания, что не хочется читать огромную простыню не представляя заранее о чем она. В научных статьях, например, всегда есть вступление описывающее тему - т.н. abstract.

Comment: Заголовок вопроса зачем?

Comment: Заголовка мало. У книги/статьи тоже есть название/заголовок, но его недостаточно для раскрытия сути. Всего лишь пытаюсь вам помочь, сделать вопрос более доступным.

Comment: Я привлекаю читателя в начале вопроса ;)

Comment: @СергейГрушин ну видите - читатель не очень-то привлекается таким способом. Большинство участников SO - люди занятые, у каждого полно своей работы.

Comment: Организованное заминусование? Я уже сам нашёл ответ.

Comment: @СергейГрушин если у вас есть ответ - опубликуйте его. Может ещё кому-то пригодится

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нашёл решение. Делается все проще

1. Скачать библиотеку в jar
2. Рядом с папкой src создать папку libs
3. Положить туда jar с библиотекой
4. Долго нажать и выбрать Ad library to project

Сверху начнёт выполняться загрузка архива, что происходит дальше я не знаю но использовал библиотеки можно.